# 3d transition between two pictures

Tags: iphone

I hope to make 3d transition between two pictures just like the slideshow 3d transition in app 'photos'.

For 2d transition, I can use CATransition.
Is there any 3D api for this?

Welcome any comment

Comment: Something like `+[UIView transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is 2.5d animation in the iphone which is basiclly simulated 3d environment. you can do it by doing a 3dtransform to a layer and mov it in the Z Axis.

Heres a code sample

First you should set the vision point or the "Camera" by doing this :

```
CATransform3D perspective = CATransform3DIdentity;
perspective.m34 = -0.001;
self.view.layer.sublayerTransform = perspective;
```

then you just add BasicAnimation to your layer and change the y property

```
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.y"];
animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:M_PI];
animation.duration = 10;
[imageView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"Transform"];
```

this sample code will make a 3d rotation to the image